# How to define a new command line program?

Tags: node.js, cmd, command-line-interface

I'm trying to define a command line program which will automatically call a specified Nodejs application.

I want to define it like that:

```
mycommand newFile
```

And that will call this application:

```
node E:/nodejsApp/mycommand.js newFile
```

`mycommand.js` is ready now. I want to call it with directly `mycommand` command on cmd in Windows 10.

Comment: Create an alias or a mycommand.cmd that calls node

Comment: Take a look at [`doskey`](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) to define macros (command aliases), or put `node E:/nodejsApp/mycommand.js %1` into a batch script named `mycommand.cmd`…

Comment: @Marged you're true. Could you please write this as answer with more spesific details, so anyone who want this would reach it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that, create a batch file in your path (ex: C:\WINDOWS\System32) with that code:
`node E:\nodejsApp\mycommand.js %1`

Save it as the command you want to create + the batch extension (`[command].bat`)

Another option will be, as aschipfl mentioned, use the `doskey` command creating an autorun. Note that I recommend creating the batch file, as running a command at starting of CMD will slow down his starting.

For the AutoRun, create a registry key at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` called `AutoRun`, type `REG_MULTI_SZ` and write the value of `doskey mycommand=node E:\nodejsApp\mycommand.js %1`